.NET MAUI: The App is breaking with custom WebView on the iOS Platform
We are using a webview to show the HTML data on the UI. We add a custom webview to increase the font size of the html data in ios platform.
MyWebView
public class MyWebView : WebView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty UrlProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    propertyName: "Url",
    returnType: typeof(string),
    declaringType: typeof(MyWebView),
    defaultValue: default(string));

    public string Url
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UrlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UrlProperty, value); }
    }
}

MyWebViewRenderer in ios
public class MyWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<MyWebView, WKWebView>
{
    WKWebView _wkWebView;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MyWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
            config.AllowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;
            _wkWebView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
            //transparent background
            _wkWebView = new WKWebView(CGRect.Empty, config);
            _wkWebView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
            _wkWebView.ScrollView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
            _wkWebView.Opaque = false;
            _wkWebView.NavigationDelegate = new MyNavigationDelegate();
            SetNativeControl(_wkWebView);

        }
    }

    public class MyNavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
    {
        public override void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
        {
            string fontSize = "";
            if (DeviceInfo.Idiom == DeviceIdiom.Phone)
            {
                fontSize = "500%"; // > 100% shows larger than previous
            }
            else if (DeviceInfo.Idiom == DeviceIdiom.Tablet)
            {
                fontSize = "750%"; // > 100% shows larger than previous
            }

            string stringsss = String.Format(@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '{0}'", fontSize);
            WKJavascriptEvaluationResult handler = (NSObject result, NSError err) =>
            {
                if (err != null)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(err);
                }
                if (result != null)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(result);
                }
            };
            webView.EvaluateJavaScript(stringsss, handler);
        }

    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == "Url")
        {

            string finalHtml = Element.Url.Replace("width=\"640\"", "width=\"1000\"");
            Control.LoadHtmlString(finalHtml, null);
        }
    }
}

Added below code on MauiProgram:
handlers.AddCompatibilityRenderer(typeof(Marian_Consecration.Renderers.MyWebView), typeof(Marian_Consecration.Platforms.iOS.Renderers.MyWebViewRenderer));

While running we get the below exception:
Exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: Application Name.Platforms.iOS.Renderers.MyWebViewRenderer will work with AddHandler. Please use AddHandler instead of AddCompatibilityRenderer.
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals.Registrar.CheckIfRendererIsCompatibilityRenderer(Type rendererType)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Hosting.MauiHandlersCollectionExtensions.AddCompatibilityRenderer(IMauiHandlersCollection handlersCollection, Type controlType, Type rendererType)
at App_name.MauiProgram.

After getting above exception we changed the AddCompatibilityRenderer to AddHandler on MauiProgram.cs and the app is not breaking with that exception. But on the html UI we can't view the data.
The above code we used on the xamarin forms and it was working fine. So for MAUI any additional changes do we need to make for the proper working?

You may customize your WebView using MAUI Handler. You don't have to use Renderer.
Let's say you have a WebView in XAML,
<local:MyWebView WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300" .../>

And in code behind, just customize the WebView Handler,
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ModifyWebView();

    }


    void ModifyWebView()
    {
        Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WebViewHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>
        {
            if (view is MyWebView)
            {
                MyWebView myWebView = view as MyWebView;
                
#if IOS
             if (handler.PlatformView != null)
             {
                var webView = (WKWebView)handler.PlatformView;
                webView.NavigationDelegate = new MyNavigationDelegate();
             }              
#endif
            }

        });
    }

Here is the WKNavigationDelegate in code behind, which is almost the same as your code,
#if IOS
    class MyNavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
    {

        public override void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
        {
         ...
        }
    }
#endif

For more info, you may also refer to Invoke platform code.

Using ipad pro12.9 ios17.4
Screenshot (before using Handler):

Screenshot (after using Handler):


I have a few clarifications on this. 1. In my current implementation do we need MyWebView in solution and MyWebViewRenderer in ios platform. 2. I am getting error for WKWebView and MyNavigationDelegate, any using statements is missed on your solution?. 3. Where should I add the MyNavigationDelegate code? Could you please explain in detail?


I create customize MyWebView as you did but do not use MyWebViewRenderer. Instead, I use Handler to customize the webview 2. May I know what error you get? You may try adding using UIKit using Foundation using WebKit  3.  MyNavigationDelegate you can just put it in code behind.


shuld i delete MyWebViewRenderer from ios platform to test this?

For testing, you could just comment out this line in MauiProgram.cs, handlers.AddCompatibilityRenderer(typeof(Marian_Consecration.Renderers.MyWebView), typeof(Marian_Consecration.Platforms.iOS.Renderers.MyWebViewRenderer));

It is working on iPhone, the font size is increased. but no change in ipad devices

if (DeviceInfo.Idiom == DeviceIdiom.Phone)
{
fontSize = "500%"; // > 100% shows larger than previous
}
else if (DeviceInfo.Idiom == DeviceIdiom.Tablet)
{
fontSize = "750%"; // > 100% shows larger than previous
}  I tried 1000, but no change in ipad

i tried with 2000, but no change in ipad

What ipad and ios version do you use?

17.4 for both iphone and ipad

Did you get a chance to check the iPad issue?

I tried ipad pro12.9 ios17.4 but found no issue. You could check my screenshot in my answer. You may try cleaning the project, delete bin and obj folder and rebuilt it.
